# Reset field in remix-validated-form

Tags: remix

I am working with remix-validated-form, and I have an entry that is an array. I will process as many inputs as this according to the value of another input. It works fine, but every time I render a new input, I get the old values that the user typed.

Do you know how I can remove the old value that the user typed in so that I don't keep them and leave the new list of inputs with no value?

This is my component:

```
constant repeat = new array(X)

repeat.fill(10).map(item => (
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder = "Enter a number"
      name="internal number"
    />
))
```

The X value is another value set in a dropdown, and when I submit the form I get `internalNumber[0]` etc with the correct value. It's ok, and what I expect.

If I update, and choose another number in the dropdown, the number of inputs I render is fine, but the value is the same as before, and I can't reset the value of the input array to 0, do you know how can I do it using remix-validated-form library?

Thanks in advance